# Material Design support library

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, material-design, android-design-library

Are there efforts underway to backport the new Material Design style and widgets to pre-L versions of Android, similar to the "HoloEverywhere"-library? The creator of that library has initialized an empty GitHub-repository, but it doesn't seem to be in active development. I know there is a backport of L-style dialogs and the floating action button, but there are obviously so many more widgets that have changed in Android L.

Has the Android team made any announcement whether they are working on a support library (exceeding what's currently available)?

Comment: Yes, there are plans to update the support library for Material.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, Alan! Great to hear that.

Comment: **What** Github repository? Could you post a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) is the way. Just add this to your Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is complex answer for you

## Material Design from Android 2.2 (API 8) to present 5.0 (API 21)

Here what you need:

1. Toolbar
2. Material Design Library for widgets (*buttons, checkboxes, etc*)

### **1. Toolbar**

Just get the idea and you ready to go.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Setup guide: http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/

Source with example: https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere

To make **Toolbar** work lower **API 11** use **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** (*instead windowActionBar set to false*)

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
</style>
```

### **2. Material Design Library**

Here is **Material Design Library** for pretty buttons, etc.. Currently it's heavily developed.

Guide, code, example - https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Guide how to add library to **Android Studio 1.0** - [How do I import material design library to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364565/how-to-import-material-design-library-to-android-studio)

.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

See: [AppCompat V21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```