# How do I import material design library to Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, material-design

I want to import this library to my project in [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) v1.0.0 rc2:

https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

But there is a problem. When I add this library as a module, this error appears:

> Error:Dependency MyApplication.libraries:MaterialDesign:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\ADTBundle\StudioWorkspace\MyApplication\libraries\MaterialDesign\build\outputs\apk\MaterialDesign-release-unsigned.apk

What would be a step-by-step guide to solve this problem? Or what would be a gradle dependency for this library?

Comment: In general it looks like you're trying to import an APK, which isn't a valid library type. An APK is a full installable Android application file, not a library. You should include it as source or look for a JAR or AAR archive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio:

- You can import the project as a module and change the following in the `build.gradle` file of the imported module.
- Change apply plugin: `com.android.application` to apply plugin: `com.android.library`
  remove  `applicationId` and set `minSdkVersion` to match your project minSdkVersion.
- And in your project `build.gradle` file `compile project(':MaterialDesignLibrary')`, where `MaterialDesignLibrary` is the name of your library project or you can import the module by File -> Project Structure -> Select your project under Modules -> Dependencies -> Click on + to add a module.

Comment: I had the same problem. I did exactly as you suggested. It built successfully. But when I tried to run it, this error came up; Error:(25, 32) error: cannot find symbol class myLib

Comment: I found the solution. Have to set minifyEnabled false for it to work, else the class myLib could not be found.

Comment: am using android studio v1.0.2. please help me to how can i add already existing project into android studio and set that project as support libreary project like in eclipse.

Comment: I don't get an "apply plugin" line. I get "configurations.create("default")" and an artifacts.add statement.

Answer (score 44):

There is a new official design library,
just add this to your build.gradle: for details [visit android developers page](https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
```

Comment: how to compile gradle? how to use this?

Comment: @NitinKarale http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: How do I know which version number to use?

Comment: @ScottBiggs try the latest stable one

Comment: @WhereDatApp.com Thanks for your help! How do I know what the latest stable version number is?  Guessing is a very tedious process.

Comment: Just google "material design support library", e.g. https://developer.android.com/training/material/design-library.html
@ScottBiggs

Comment: Upgrade the dependency to implementation

Answer (score 28):

If u are using Android X: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/ follow the instruction here

when last edited the latest library version was

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
```

**Update** : Get latest material design library from here
https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.google.android.material#com.google.android.material:material

**For older SDK**

Add the design support library version as same as of your **appcompat-v7** library

You can get the latest library from android developer documentation
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#design

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'

Answer (score 8):

Goto

1. File (Top Left Corner)
2. Project Structure
3. Under Module. Find the Dependence tab
4. press plus button (+) at top right.
5. You will find all the dependencies

Answer (score 4):

If you migrated to AndroidX you should add the dependency in graddle like this:

`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01`

Answer (score 3):

The latest as of release of API 23 is

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add the Material Design dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
```

To get the latest material design library version. check the official website [github repository](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases).

Current version is **1.2.0**.

So, you have to add,

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
```

Then, you need to change the app theme to material theme by adding,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

in your **style.xml**. Dont forget to set the same theme in your application theme in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

styles.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add latest libraries support to old project by putting all these inside **app:level gradle.build** like this

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    
    
   // rest code

    dependencies {
        implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
}
```