# migrating to material design

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I am trying to migrate my android application to material design. I am following [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) tutorial.
However, when I try to build or run the app,I get the following errors

```
/home/shimba/kaa/kAA/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/values-v11/values.xml
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/shimba/kaa/kAA/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/values-v14/values.xml
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
/home/shimba/kaa/kAA/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.2/res/values-v21/values.xml
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(298, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(298, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(142, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(143, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(142, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(143, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(142, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(143, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(144, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(146, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(147, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(145, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(142, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(143, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

Where am I going wrong? I am using android studio. I have the following dependencies in my gradle file

```
dependencies {
//compile project(':universalImageLoaderLibrary3')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
compile project(':universalImageLoaderLibrary3')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Please help.

Comment: For which version of android are you trying to develop ? And can you list your style file as well ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [appcompat-v7:21.0.0': No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro)

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android Studio. and Check the errors in the file values.xml file.

Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
These are the attributes which are missing in your xml.

Check the identifiers you've given also.

Answer (score 0):

Use this style in your style.xml folder Instead of using Material if your device is below V5.0

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">     
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/lite_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/lite_blue</item>
</style>
```

r If you are using device with V5.0 Then use This

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/lite_blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/lite_blue</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complex answer for you

## Material Design from Android 2.2 (API 8) to present 5.0 (API 21)

Here what you need:

1. Toolbar
2. Material Design Library for widgets (*buttons, checkboxes, etc*)

### **1. Toolbar**

Just get the idea and you ready to go.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Setup guide: http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/

Source with example: https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere

To make **Toolbar** work lower **API 11** use **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** (*instead windowActionBar set to false*)

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
</style>
```

### **2. Material Design Library**

Here is **Material Design Library** for pretty buttons, etc.. Currently it's heavily developed.

Guide, code, example - https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Guide how to add library to **Android Studio 1.0** - [How do I import material design library to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364565/how-to-import-material-design-library-to-android-studio)

.

Have I answered your question?)