# Material Design theme in android

Tags: android, material-design

I am learn about how to apply theme in app.

```
<style name="Theme.BaseApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

When we use `android:colorPrimary` line.

Please help me.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Please clarify the problem you're currently facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really know what are you asking for. You set `@color/colorPrimary` in a separeate colors.xml file. Then after you assign your color to 
`<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>` it will be automatically used for some things in the theme like notification bar etc

Example:

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#0D47A1</color>
    <color name="accent">#FF9800</color>
</resources>
```

You can then use those colors to keep consistent color palette over your app.

Comment: android:colorPrimary this line give me error in v21 lower devices.

Comment: because in API < 21 you need to use Theme.AppCompat as the parent of your theme as in <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Answer (score 0):

Here is complex answer for you

## Material Design from Android 2.2 (API 8) to present 5.0 (API 21)

Here what you need:

1. Toolbar
2. Material Design Library for widgets (*buttons, checkboxes, etc*)

### **1. Toolbar**

Just get the idea and you ready to go.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

Setup guide: http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/

Source with example: https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere

To make **Toolbar** work lower **API 11** use **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** (*instead windowActionBar set to false*)

```
<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
</style>
```

### **2. Material Design Library**

Here is **Material Design Library** for pretty buttons, etc.. Currently it's heavily developed.

Guide, code, example - https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Guide how to add library to **Android Studio 1.0** - [How do I import material design library to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364565/how-to-import-material-design-library-to-android-studio)

.

Hope it helps :)