# Can't import Material Design Library in android studio

Tags: android-studio, material-design, android-design-library

I read this [page](http://www.crowbarsolutions.com/importing-libraries-into-android-studio), that learn "**importing libraries into android studio**". but it's doesn't work for me. i do those step for **[Material Design Library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)**. in Material Design's `build.gradle` file have:

https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesign/build.gradle

when i click on "**Sync Project with Gradle Files**" it's gives me two error:

1. `Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.`
2. `Error:(3, 0) Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.bintray' not found.`

Can any one tell me how to solve those error's?

**note**: i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364565/how-to-import-material-design-library-to-android-studio), but don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont follow the above tutorial, the shown approach is useful when the library has not published as maven or gradle dependency.But as Github page say it is published on maven.

So remove the module or library project completely from your project and use gradle dependency instead.

Just copy this in your `app` module's build.gradle inside dependencies closure

```
dependencies {
     // YOUR OTHER DEPENDENCIES
     compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
}
```

Sync your project with gradle.

Comment: erorr say: `Error:Failed to find: com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+
Open File  Open in Project Structure dialog`

Comment: working perfectly for me, make sure you are connected to internet.

Comment: @pyus13 ,i don't have **maven** in my android studio **Settings**. is that error's because of this?

Comment: sorry did not get you, maven and jcenter are central repositories

Comment: thanks,yes i can't access internet **1**. blocking java by windows firewall and **2**. i unchecked `Gradle work offline` in android studio ( i not sure about second step)

Comment: Great, happy to hear that your problem got resolved .. Enjoy dude :)

Comment: @pyus13 thanks, it's work. but how about this:https://github.com/navasmdc/PhoneTutorial?

Comment: also you may need to include the project in settings.gradle file of the project like include ':app',':MaterialDesign' then you can see auto complete working for typing tag "<com." in any of your layout files

Comment: gradle build fails with ExecException. Duplicate file ic_launcher from drawable-hdpi-v4. There are libpng warnings.libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited. Shown up for images from another library

Comment: why do we need to add this `@aar` at the end, cuz I remember at some times we don't need to add this.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to download the Material Design Library and import it without using the gradle method pyus13 mentioned, you need to add the following lines to the *MaterialDesign* Build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
    }
}
```

To find this file, you can double click on the error you get when syncing that looks like this:

```
Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.
```

I also had to add `compile project(':MaterialDesign')` to the app build.gradle file.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Tried by gradle and importing module didn't work, but this answer did the workaround!!!

Answer (score 0):

This was kindly answered @pyus13 but I would like to give the complete answer, with the source, [github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#howtouse](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#howtouse):

> You can use the gradle dependency, you have to add these lines in your
>   build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar'
}
```

The `build.gradle` you are looking for is in `ProjectName\app\src`.

Comment: If you need first to remove an already included module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio/27404458#27404458

Answer (score 0):

Add two dependencies in your **Project build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
}
```