# What dependency I need to add to use com.google.android.material.slider.Slider

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components, android-slider

What dependency I need to add to my Android Studio project to use this component?
And, in general, how to know what dependency I need to add to use a Google Material component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import material design library to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364565/how-do-i-import-material-design-library-to-android-studio)

Comment: Before asking a question you should google it first! Or check if the answer is already present on stack overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-rc01'
```

The [`Slider`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md) components was introduced with the version `1.2.0-alpha01`