# How do I add Material Components to Android Studio's Palette?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I'd like to see Material Components for Android, such as `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView`, in the "Design" view's Palette menu when editing a layout xml file.

The [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364565/how-do-i-import-material-design-library-to-android-studio) was to add:

```kotlin
implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
```

to `app/build.gradle`, but this design library is no longer updated in favor of AndroidX, which I'm using.

Is it still possible to add Material Components to the Palette menu for drag-and-drog use?